# Android 10 on killed of app(i.e. swiped out app from recent apps) the job scheduler to detect internet is not working

Tags: android, background-process, job-scheduling, android-10.0, jobservice

I have created a job scheduler which is started by a job service to detect when the device connects to network. But this scheduler doesn't work on android 10 devices.

`

```
try {
        ComponentName componentName = 
                        new ComponentName(SplashScreenActivity.this,JobSchedulerService.class);

        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(13, componentName)
                          .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                          .setPersisted(true)
                           .build();

       JobScheduler jobScheduler = 
                    (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                        int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
                        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                            Log.d("Job", "Job scheduled!");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Job", "Job not scheduled");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        Logger.e(getApplicationContext(), "SplashScreenActivity", "Job-", ex);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some details, like what exactly does not work, or like error messages, or what you have already learned by yourself.

Comment: "swiped out app from recent apps) the job scheduler to detect internet is not working" -- the behavior of a device when the user swipes an app out of an overview screen depends on the device manufacturer. Some manufacturers treat this as the same as "Force Stop" in Settings, and that will cancel all outstanding jobs and alarms. There is very little that you can do about this.

Comment: thank you, @CommonsWare is there any work around for this?

Comment: @Markus-Hermann there is n  error message, the job scheduler is killed on kill of the app. This is how i want it to work as: When i kill the app and if i turn off and on my network , the job scheduler must detect this change in network.

Comment: As I wrote, there is very little that you can do about this. You will need to have your app be able to cope with the fact that background jobs may get canceled as a result of user action.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for the info